# Tying in facebook comments plugin with Facebook Developer App

Tags: facebook, dotnetnuke, facebook-comments

First off, thanks for taking the time to read this.

I have successfully added the facebook comments plugin to multiple pages on my website. I am looking for the central location to view all comments made on my website, and to moderate them.

From my google research I have found that I need to create a "Facebook App" that is assigned to the comments plugin, ad myself as an administrator, and thats it.

I was able to create my facebook developers account, and I stumbled through trying to make the associated comments app, but I have been met with utter failure :(

How do I create a Facebook app that is tied into the facebook comments plugin on my site? Can anyone point me to a good resource?

Thanks 
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible ways to moderate comments from the [Comments plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/):

## 1

Add this `<meta property="fb:admins" content="{YOUR_FACEBOOK_USER_ID}"/>` with `YOUR_FACEBOOK_USER_ID` correctly set to your `<head>`.
You should since be able to moderate comments.

Note:

> to add multiple moderators, separate the uids by comma without spaces.

## 2

Now, if you wish to have a larger control over your app:

- Add this `<meta property="fb:app_id" content="{YOUR_APPLICATION_ID}"/>` with `YOUR_APPLICATION_ID` correctly set to your `<head>`,
- In the [app's settings](https://developers.facebook.com/apps), you will be able to add as many administrators as you want,
- Moderate comments from [here](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments) through one administrator's account.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Stephane. I have found that my issue resides with my CMS, and that it is not correctly applying header information on generated pages. I'll start a new thread to track this down.